# How to make the carousel selected with an event click on angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make some tutos on Angular to learn. I have created a component slideshow that contains a bootstrap carousel, and in the parent component I have created two divs that trigger the action of showing and hiding the carousel.

I have set the focus on ngb-carousel component when set focus event it trigged, because I would like to immediately be able to use the keyboard arrows and not have to click the arrows on the screen to enable the keyboard arrows to work.

here you can find the source code:
https://github.com/agentjoseph007/slideshow

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the following line in Slideshow component -> ngAfterViewInit

```
this.carousel.first.focused = true;
```

with

```
this.carousel.first.focus();
```